# For spark, what is the fastest data structure to reduce over? Maps or lists of tuples?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce, distributed

My data could exist in rdds of two forms, either

```
RDD[Map[String, Map[String, Int]]]
```

or as

```
RDD[List[(String, List[(String,Int)])]]
```

As you can see, in the second example the "mapping" of the data is enforced by the first element of the tuple being the key. Consider two entries in my rdd, call them R1 and R2. I'll be merging by keys in R1 and R2. When R1 and R2 both contain the same key, I do further merging on those values. As an example, say that both R1 and R2 contain an entry

```
outer_key1 -> (inner_key1 -> 1)
```

then the resulting merge will produce

```
outer_key1 -> (inner_key1 -> 2)
```

So, my question is which data structure is faster and more memory efficient for spark to reduce by outer and inner key? Maps of maps or lists of (key, list_of_tuple). My intuition is that maps would be faster at reducing by key, given their 0(1) lookup. However, given the way that most maps are implemented, I'm sure that there is a decent amount of wasted memory for the map based RDDS.

As a real life example of this type of merging, my RDDs are representing

```
Map(email_address->(date->number_of_emails_recieved_that_day)) where each RDD contains many email addresses
```

Comment: Depends on whether you wan to have `findByKey` access or `sequentialAccess` over your inner data.

Comment: And your RDD is a `RDD[T]` where `T` is `Map[String, Map[String, Int]]`. Its not a `RDD[(K, T)]` so what do you mean by `Key` ??

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mis-understood about the concept of RDD's. You need to transform your data into appropriate structure to leverage the power of RDD's.

SO, you need to think about what you want to compute for deciding your RDD's.

As per my understanding of your question. You have 2 data source and you want to merge the data that you got from these 2 data sources. So you create your 2 RDD's from these sources then you merge them.

```
// First we will have to create RDD's from our data source.    

// create RDD from source 1
// Lets say you have a List[(String, List[(String, Int)]]
val src1 = List(
  ("email1@example.com", List(("01/01/2016", 10), ("05/01/2016", 20)))
  ("email2@example.com", List(("01/01/2016", 5), ("06/01/2016", 30))
)

// Now enters spark
val rddSrc1: RDD[(String, List[String, Int])] = sc.parallelize(src1)


// create RDD from source 2
// Lets say you have a Map[(String, Map[String, Int]]
val src2 = Map(
  "email1@example.com" -> Map("01/01/2016" -> 10, "05/01/2016" -> 20)
  "email2@example.com" -> Map("01/01/2016" -> 5, "06/01/2016" -> 30)
)

// Now enters spark
val rddSrc1: RDD[(String, Map[String, Int])] = sc.parallelize(src2.toList)


// Now since you want to merge on both "email" and "date" lets make ("email", "date") tuple as key.

rddSrc1T: RDD[(String, String), Int] = rddSrc1
  .flatMap({
     case (email, list) => list.map({
       case (date, number) => ((email, date), number)
     })
   })

rddSrc2T: RDD[(String, String), Int] = rddSrc1
  .flatMap({
     case (email, map) => map.toList.map({
       case (date, number) => ((email, date), number)
     })
   })

// now co-group the 2 RDD's
rddCogroup: RDD[((String, String), Iterable[Int], Iterable[Int])) = rddSrc1T.cogroup(rddSrc2T)

val totalNumberRdd: RDD[((String, String), Int] = rddCogroup.map({
  case ((email, date), iter1, iter2) => ((email, date), iter1.sum + iter2.sum)
})
```

Comment: (not familiar with anything here, but it appears your variable names aren't correct, e.g., src1/src2 being called list/map in parallelize)

Comment: yup... that is a typing mistake.

Comment: @Will Are you thinking of giving Scala a go ?

Comment: Not at this time.  Came here from a [meta] question. But it did lead me to read up on the project.  Interesting.  I'll keep it in mind if I ever come across a need for big data crunching.